# How to append query string on each a tag on an AMP page?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I am trying to append a query string to every link on an AMP page. following is my code:
Javascript Code:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),length = a.length;

for(var i=0; i< length; i++){
  a[i].href += '?key=value';
}
```

HTML Code:

```html
<amp-script layout="container" src="https://example.com/custom.js">
</amp-script>
```

How does amp-script work. Am I using it right?
The scripts not working.

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: The scripts not working.

Comment: you don't have any anchor `a` elements in your HTML, The length would be 0 and the loop never works. If the tag is 'amp-script' replace 'a' with 'amp-script' in the select and .href with .src

Comment: I have, multiple a tags in my body tag.

Comment: create a fiddle or a codepen to recreate the issue. Very little information in the question above to work with.

Comment: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/

Comment: write your js and link it to the page using <amp-script src="yourjs.js"><amp-script>>

Answer (score 0):

AMP framework supports custom scripting through **AMP-SCRIPT** component.
Here is an example

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
<body>  
  <amp-script layout="container" src="https://example.com/your_scripts.js">
    <p>Any content that can be modified from javascript</p>
  </amp-script>
</body>
</html>
```

*All event triggers are allowed*

**AMP Documentation**

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/?format=websites

Comment: Thanks for explaining the scenario. What would be the case if you want to alter href attribute of all a tags in the body?
Do I need to wrap whole markup into <amp-script></amp-script>?

Comment: AMP-Script runs your custom javascript in a Web worker (Web workers are a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads) that contains a virtual DOM. When your javascript code modifies this virtual DOM, amp-script forwards these changes to the main thread and applies them to the amp-script element subtree.

Comment: For example, adding an element to document.body:

//your_script.js
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = 'I am added to the body!';
document.body.appendChild(p);

Will be reflected on the page as a new child of the amp-script element:

<amp-script src="https://example.com/your_scripts.js" width="300" height="100">
<p>I am added to the body!</p>
</amp-script>